# Sql Server Full text Search - How to remove 'for' from stop list or noise list

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, noise-words

In sql server my search text is like

'for her' 
'for kids'

but this is ignored by the search, is there a way to remove 'for' from the noise list

Comment: If you're worried about performance, write the query in different ways and benchmark each one. There's no other way to tell.

Comment: As for checking join order, again write the query in the various different ways and use the SQL profiler to check what SQL is generated for each one.